# Eclipse Java - invalid package name - Reserved words in package name

Tags: java, android, eclipse, package

I am in the middle of an android project and was trying to create a new package in it.

```
com.mycompany.myprojectname.new
```

Well, Eclipse is not letting me to create it and is showing this error:

> Invalid package name. 'new' is not a valid Java identifier

I never knew package name has reserved words, which we cannot use. My questions are;

1. Is this an Eclipse thing? or a Java thing? I tried a pure Java project
   (not Android), just to check, but there also I got the same error.
2. What are other reserved words that is not allowed?
3. Is there any documentation about this?

Comment: 4. Have you googled about reserved words in Java?

Comment: I know I can't use resereved words in programs. But I am talking about package names

Comment: And I think your package name is a part of your program. Isn't it?

Comment: @RohitJain I believe package name is something that is in the project level, not in the program level. Anyway Joachim Sauer's answer is authoritative enough.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Yes, this is a general Java thing.

The [list of reserved words can be found here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html). They are:

> ```
> abstract  continue    for         new         switch
> assert    default     goto        package     synchronized
> boolean   do          if          private     this
> break     double      implements  protected   throw
> byte      else        import      public      throws
> case      enum        instanceof  return      transient
> catch     extends     int         short       try
> char      final       interface   static      void
> class     finally     long        strictfp    volatile
> const     float       native      super       while
> ```

Documentation on the fact that reserved words can not be used in package names if found in the [package naming tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html), among other places.

The authoritative source is (as always) [the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/index.html), specifically:

- [§ 3.9 Keywords](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.9) and
- [§ 3.8 Identifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8)

  > An identifier cannot have the same spelling (Unicode character sequence) as a keyword ([§3.9](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.9)), boolean literal ([§3.10.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.3)), or the null literal ([§3.10.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.7)), or a compile-time error occurs.

Comment: What are the rules about which characters are allowed for the package name on Android ? is it just English letters, the "." and the "_" characters that are allowed?

Comment: @androiddeveloper: (almost) all Unicode characters are allowed in Java. And unless Android has other, more specific, requirements (I'm not aware of any) the same should be true there.

Comment: I think that underscore isn't allowed as the first character, for example. I think it's the same as on Java. Can you please tell me of other rules?

Comment: I don't see underscore and/or other character being mentioned there.

Comment: So they say there that it must start with a Java-letter, yet they include the underscore and dollar sign in the mix, and I don't think it's allowed to use them as the first character, no?

Comment: Seems you are correct, at least about pure Java. On Android, however, the package name of the app must start with a real english letter: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html .  Not sure about the rest.

Comment: con is not allowed, either.

Comment: @JohannesFlügel: but that one's not up to Java, it's not a reserved word. It's just that you can't have a file or directory named `con` on Windows. In Linux you wouldn't have a problem.

Answer (score 2):

See docs here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html

> In some cases, the internet domain name may not be a valid package
>   name. This can occur if the domain name contains a hyphen or other
>   special character, if the package name begins with a digit or other
>   character that is illegal to use as the beginning of a Java name, or
>   **if the package name contains a reserved Java keyword**, such as "int".

Answer (score 1):

`new` is a java keyword. Use some other word instead of it.

Answer (score 0):

YMMV but be careful naming packages `target`; may mess with your code repository and/or IDE